# Вопрос насчёт SelectMenu в Discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как подставить под value эмбед? Чтобы при выборе в меню, сообщение изменялось на эмбед

```js
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton, MessageSelectMenu, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async (client,message,args,prefix) => {
  const ex1 = new MessageEmbed() // Создаём наш эмбэд
        .setColor('#43e2f7') // Цвет нашего сообщения
        .setTitle('Приветик :>') // Название эмбэд сообщения
        .setAuthor(message.guild.name) // Автором будет название сервера
        .setDescription(':^Мы любим вас!^:') // комментарий
        .setTimestamp() // Дата  отправки сообщения
        .setFooter('Ваш бот © 2021');
  const selectMenu = new MessageSelectMenu()
   .setCustomId('select')
   .setPlaceholder('Ничего')
   .addOptions([
     {
       label: 'Первый',
       description: 'Описание',
       value: `Первый` // Как сюда embed подставить??
     },
     {
       label: 'Второй',
       description: 'Описание2',
       value: `Второй`
     },
   ])
   .setMaxValues(1);
   const menu = new MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(selectMenu);
    message.channel.send({content: 'ЫЫ', components: [menu]});
    message.delete().catch();
  }
  module.exports.help = {
      name: "menu" // Название команды
  };
```

В index.js:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
  if (interaction.isButton() && interaction.customId == "archive") {
    interaction.reply({ content: 'Pong!', ephemeral: true });
  }
  if (interaction.isSelectMenu() && interaction.customId == "select") {
    interaction.update({ content: `${interaction.values[0]}`});
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Если сообщение будет меняться, то тогда select пропадет. Если так задумано, то в таком случае можно попробовать навешать слушатель на выбираемый элемент в списке и при нажатии удалять сообщение с select-ом и отправлять embed. Либо просто отправлять embed.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Просто слушаешь событие нажатия на меню if(interaction.isSelectMenu()) и редачишь сообщение interaction.update({content: "что-то или пустота", embeds: [указывешь что-то или пустота], components: [что-то или пустота]})

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).